# How to Uniformly distribute svg circles in d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm going for a bubble chart visualization, which is possible by using the scatterplot. However, I dont have explicit x,y coordinates for the circles and I want to simple evenly and uniformly distribute them in the svg body. The following distributes them along a line - I want a nice bubble chart effect instead.

```
   //Width and height
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 1000;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("class", "bubble")

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([10, 100]);


    circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        return (i * 50) + 25;
        })
    .attr("cy", h/2)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return scale(d[1][1]);
    })
    .attr("fill", "yellow")
    .attr("stroke", "orange")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return 100*d[1][1]/2;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your dataset is and how you want to map it the `cx`, `cy`, `r`, and `fill` attributes of your data. As you've done for `r`, you can supply functions that act on each element in your dataset and return the desired value. I recommend using scales for x and y as well as r, and renaming them so you can tell them apart. There are also some great [color scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors). Your radius scale should be a square root scale (`d3.scale.sqrt()`), not linear, so that the bubble's area encodes data rather than its height. (For this reason, visualization thought leaders [advise you against bubbles](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/our_fascination_with_all_things_circular.pdf).)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, your dataset may have 48 items (for example) and you want to display circles eight across and six up (for example)?

Try this:

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i){return i%8 * 50 + 25;})
.attr("cy", function(d,i){return Math.floor(i/8) * 50 + 25;})
```